# Tomcat webapp resources 404 response

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

I am converting an existing tomcat application to docker, however, while almost everything works, all requests for resources respond with a `404` error. I have copied the WAR file and renamed it to ROOT so no prefix should be necessary.

I also have an alternative way to access resources using `/javax.faces.resource/images/Logo.png.xhtml` which works, but `/resources/images/Logo.png` doesn't.

This is the folder structure:

```
webapps:
  ROOT:
    META-INF:
      # Various files
    WEB-INF:
      # Various files
    various.xhtml: # Works
    favicon.ico: # Can't reach also
    resources: # Can't reach anything in here
      css:
        # Various files
      images:
        Logo.png:
      js:
        # Various files
  ROOT.war:
```

Is there some kind of configuration file that I am missing?
This is using tomcat:7-jdk8

Shortened `web.xml`, full version linked in comments:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">

    <!-- Spring configuration -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
        <param-value>webapp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>noCache</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>resourceCache</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>expires</param-name>
            <!-- <param-value>1m</param-value>  -->
            <param-value>1h</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>resourceCache</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/favicon.ico</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/organization/logo/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- JSF Servlet registration / url mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you please show us your web.xml?

Comment: @Woworks here is the gist for it: https://gist.github.com/RedlineTriad/74e88f3bc2525d335a59fe38ed7bf180

Comment: @redline. People trying to help you will look for the relevant information directly in your question. Please edit your question and add the relevant information in a code block.

Comment: Can you try to add  <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern> to your Faces Servlet mapping section (where you already have <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>)

Comment: @Woworks still just 404